# custom directive in angularjs without usage of ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Help, please, with such question - I request through $resource ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos') json object, render in view the list- picture-thumbnail (property 'thumbnailUrl') and text (property 'title'). Object property 'url' is the reference on full-size picture.
The task - to create the directive as attribute of each list element - when we click on element, the screen is getting dark and the full-size picture should be shown in the center of the screen; then when we click on any place of the screen the full-size picture should be hidden .
! ng-click is not allowed !

```js
(function() {
 angular.module('pictures', ['ngResource']);

 angular.module('pictures')
  .controller("PicturesController", ['picturesService', PicturesController]);

  function PicturesController(picturesService) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.pictures = picturesService.query();
  };

 angular.module('pictures')
  .factory("picturesService", ['$resource', picturesService]);

  function picturesService($resource) {
   return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', {});
  };
 
 angular.module('pictures')
  .directive('showFull', ['$document', showFull]);

  function showFull($document) {
   return {
    link: ????????????????? 
   };
  };
 
  
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='pictures'>
<head>
 <title>NG</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
 <div id='pictures-list' ng-controller='PicturesController as pictures'>
  <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat='pict in pictures.pictures' show-full>
    <img src='{{pict.thumbnailUrl}}' /> <br> {{pict.title}}
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: This is too broad and SO isn't a code writing factory where people will do your work for you. You need to show an attempt and ask questions when you are stuck with real code...not just a concept. Also if a native part of a framework like `ng-click` isn't allowed, an explanation why would help. This smells a lot like a homework assignment

Comment: What is the question here?  you posted some incomplete code with a bunch of question marks, are you wanting someone to tell you what you are supposed to write in there?